# How to knit into HTML files from RStudio on a Mac?

Tags: safari, rstudio, knitr, webarchive

I teach a data science class where I have the students type notes and homework in R markdown.  From there, RStudio usually knits documents into an HTML file.  I prefer to have the students turn in those easy-to-read HTML files for grading.  However, some of my students are using Safari and a Mac book.  Their software knits into more advanced **.webarchive** files by default.  How can we get **.html** files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below command for this:

```
textutil -convert html example.webarchive
```

But be warned that it creates all the files in the current directory, so if you have a lot of images, they will get placed there.

Hope this helps!